# how to get string from database and how to explode it in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, explode

Here is my code i tried to explode string, but get some errors,
i got string but i did not explode,
Here i getting some erros,i cant understand it
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Warning Message: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string,
>   object given Filename: views/testing.php Line Number: 65

Here is My code:

```
<?php

foreach ($test as $t)   
{                      
   echo $t->user_rights;
   $t=(explode(",", $t));                                   


 }

?>
```

Comment: what's the content of $test ???

Comment: $test is controller variable,
get data from database

Comment: it should have column name like this `$t->column_name`

Comment: echo $t->user_rights;
   $t=(explode(",", $t));

Comment: also tried it @pradeep but it did not work

Comment: can u show your $test data

Comment: yes test data is print in view,but i added explode then its not working

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($test);` show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
foreach ($test as $t)   
{   
    /* this will trigger an error since $t->user_rights is an array . 
       To use explode $t->user_rights should be a string
    */                  
    $user_rights = (explode(",", $t->user_rights));
    print_r($user_rights);                                   
}
```

**UPDATE :**

If you want a comma separated values of `user_rights` then you have to use `implode()` instead of `explode()`;

```
foreach ($test as $t)   
{                      
    $user_rights = implode(",", $t->user_rights);
    echo $user_rights ;                                   
}
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: still not work,,
error:Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_rights] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 [21] => 1 [22] => 1 [23] => 1 [24] => 1 [25] => 1 ) ) ) 
yes got it in array,,,,but now how to print it

Comment: i got output like this yes its correct, but how to print it now
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 [21] => 1 [22] => 1 [23] => 1 [24] => 1 [25] => 1 )

Comment: `$t->user_rights` has an array and if u want comma separated values of user_rights then u have use `impload` instead of `explode`, what do u say?

Comment: yes i want seprated values,so how to implement implode function

Comment: ohk Thank you dear

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can convert $t using implode($t).
such as:
$t= explode(",", implode($t));

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
foreach ($test as $t){
    $t=(explode(",",$t->user_rights));
}
?>
```

Comment: $t->user_rights should be string and in $t variable you will get array .so according to that array you can use array value.